# How to uninstall pam-auth-update safely

Tags: 20.04

How to uninstall pam-auth-update safely? I don't wanna bomb my installations with `rm`.
I don't know what's the name of the package I should erase.

It's not `pam-auth-update` even though that's the name on ubuntu's doc: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man8/pam-auth-update.8.html

I have a bunch of pam stuff locally:

```
~ $ dpkg -l | grep pam
ii  libpam-cap:amd64                              1:2.32-1                                   amd64        POSIX 1003.1e capabilities (PAM module)
ii  libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64                    3.36.0-1ubuntu1                            amd64        PAM module to unlock the GNOME keyring upon login
ii  libpam-modules:amd64                          1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1                           amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
ii  libpam-modules-bin                            1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1                           amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM - helper binaries
ii  libpam-runtime                                1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1                           all          Runtime support for the PAM library
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64                          245.4-4ubuntu3.4                           amd64        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libpam0g:amd64                                1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1                           amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules library
ii  thunderbird                                   1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1          amd64        Email, RSS and newsgroup client with integrated spam filter
```

And I'm pretty sure I installed it with `apt`.

Ubuntu 20.04 here.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think that's a core part of system security. I don't think you would have installed it. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hey PonJar, really? I didn't know, I thought I had installed it, probably was some other tool then.
It doesn't recognize my fingerprint anymore, so it's useless. I couldn't find instructions on how to create a new fingerprint and thought the easiest solution was just uninstall and install it again and tried that for a while and couldn't, so I asked here. Maybe I should close this question then and open a new one?

Comment: Yes, ask a question about the fingerprint problem.

Comment: On the other hand this guide might help you https://itsfoss.com/fingerprint-login-ubuntu/